# Is there a way to see when a certain version of a journey was activated?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, journeybuilder

I can only see the last modified date and time of all versions but no when the versions where stopped/activated. I am trying to use the documented GET /interactions/rest to find a method that retrieves the versions but I was unable to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr:
Latest version yes: `lastPublishedDate`

Other versions: no, only approximations can be done

Probably worth looking at an example to have something to talk about;

`GET https://www.exacttargetapis.com/interaction/v1/interactions/someKey`

returns a payload as can be seen below.

If I understand what you need correctly, then `lastPublishedDate` would tell you the activation date of the latest version; which version that is can be of course be seen in `version`- in the example, this journey was never activated - as it is on version 1, and looking at the timestamp either someone activated it in the year 1 AD or we are looking at the "empty" equivalent.

Activation or "publishing" as the payload calls it, always refers to a specific, namely the most current version, not the journey as a whole. You can also see that reflected that in the data view documentation:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_journey.htm&type=5

> LastPublishedDate:    The date that the version of the journey was last published

You can also see in both the payload and the data view that there seems to be no historical tracking of versions other than the current one and their publishing dates. You'd have to get creative and e.g. determine from the email sent timestamps in a specific journey version when that must have been active. This is not something you would do through the API, but SQL based using the two Data views _journey and _journeyActivity. Assuming you do have email sends in your journey. Then, a starting point (not the full solution) would likely be this:

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_query_journey_builder_sends_in_last_24_hours.htm&type=5

and that:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_query_journey_builder_sends_by_email_across_versions.htm&type=5

```
{
    "id": "292aa13b-f34b-4064-99b9-xxxxxxxxx",
    "key": "4931e622-9413-00c3-aa08-xxxxxxxxx",
    "name": "myName",
    "lastPublishedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "description": "",
    "version": 1,
    "workflowApiVersion": 1,
    "createdDate": "2018-03-19T04:35:50.21",
    "modifiedDate": "2018-03-20T10:08:38.157",
    "activities": [
        {},
        {}
    ],
    "goals": [],
    "exits": [],
    "stats": {
        "currentPopulation": 0,
        "cumulativePopulation": 0,
        "metGoal": 0,
        "metExitCriteria": 0,
        "goalPerformance": 0
    },
    "tags": [
        {
            "name": "something"
        },
        {
            "name": "something else"
        }
    ],
    "entryMode": "SingleEntryAcrossAllVersions",
    "defaults": {
        "email": [
            "{{Event.SalesforceObjcc8de50e2b153xxxxxx00be9ea6eec.\"CampaignMember:Common:Email\"}}"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "analyticsTracking": {
                "enabled": false,
                "analyticsType": "google",
                "urlDomainsToTrack": []
            }
        }
    },
    "metaData": {},
    "executionMode": "Production",
    "status": "Draft",
    "definitionId": "292aa13b-f34b-4064-99b9-xxxxxxx"
}
```